# How can I resolve bootstrap variables and reuse them in my own classes?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

How can I *resolve* and *reuse* variables coming from `_variables.scss` within my own class (`.post-body` in this case) so I don't have to add a long list of styles to my html?

This is what the relevant html line looks like:

```
<div class="col px-5 py-4 post-body">{{{ contents }}}</div>
```

And this is my `stylesheet.scss`:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions"; 
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// ...

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.post-body {
  background-color: #252526;
  color: #dddddd;
  line-height: 26px;

  // Following are my attempts to reuse $box-shadow-lg from _variables.scss

  box-shadow-lg;          // Invalid syntax
  @include box-shadow-lg; // Complains with undefined mixin.
}
```

Sure I could add them directly, like below: But as the number of modifications grows, the list of classes applied to html will grow as well and result in complexity.

```
<div class="col px-5 py-4 post-body box-shadow-lg">{{{ contents }}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out by myself. It seems that I need to `@import` the mixins. And then use that function.

```
// ...
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
// ...

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.post-body {
  background-color: #252526;
  color: #dddddd;
  line-height: 26px;
  @include box-shadow($box-shadow-lg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `@extend` from scss like this :

```
.post-body {
  background-color: #252526;
  color: #dddddd;
  line-height: 26px;

  @extend .box-shadow-lg;
}
```

So the styles of `.box-shadow-lg` would be paste to your `.post-body` class.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately this attemp does not work. When compiling it throws with `The target selector was not found.`